# Person vs Thing for determining case?

Tags: verb, grammatical-case, dative

In German, some verbs use the dative case for the object (e.g. *Ich folge dir*).  In lists about these, I've seen mention of *jemand* and *etwas*. Does the case change depending on whether the object is a person or thing?

Comment: maybe this is bad stackechange form, but basically, my question is "what is this page (and the linked pdf) talking about!?" https://mein-deutschbuch.de/liste-kasusergaenzungen-der-verben.html

Comment: @perpetual Is your confusion, because they print _jdm = Person + Dativ_ and _s. = reflexives Pronomen im Dativ_ is red, but _jdn = Person + Akkusativ, _s. = reflexives Pronomen im Akkusative_ is red, **AND** _etw = Sache + Akkusativ_ in black - which looks as if there were no _Sache + Dativ_?

Comment: my confusion is that they seem to care about jemand vs etwas.  Why not just "nomen"?  Do I really need to care about Person vs Sache?  If I write a story about a Robot, does it matter if the robot is an IT or a HE?  (I know it matters for es vs er, but will it matter for the cases). Thanks.

Comment: @perpetual English dictionary entries can look like "_to follow so./sth._" as well. This is unrelated to cases, but it is mentioned, as some verbs can only be applied to a person OR a thing - you can _help someone_, but you can't _help something_

Comment: @Marzipanherz, I accept your answer.  As an aside, I am not as accepting of the idea that some verbs only apply to people.  "I helped the house become more beautiful."  Would helfen be the wrong verb for that?  Sometimes it requires more poetry or fiction (e.g. talking cars that get stomach pains), but I don't think it's a function of the grammar as to which verbs would be wrong to use with objects. Thanks.

Comment: @perpetual Maybe _to help_ wasn't the best English example :) But I hope, you got the point. I've expanded my answer a bit regarding the living/non-living aspects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, the case does not depend on whether the object is a person or a thing.**

One can say:

> Ich folge dem Mann.
>   *[jemandem, Dativ]*
>
> Ich folge dem Auto.
>   *[etwas, Dativ]*

This is similar to English dictionary entries, for example:

> to follow so./sth.

where the distinction between *someone* and *something* is unrelated to cases as well.

---

The distinction between a person and a thing is made, because there are some verbs that usually do not make sense with a person or a thing. This is rather about word usage, less about grammar.

Consider the German verb *weh tun*, for example:

> Dem Mann tut der Bauch weh.
>   *[jemandem, Dativ]*
>
> Dem Auto tut der Bauch weh.
>   *[etwas, Dativ]*

The second example is perfectly fine from the grammatical point of view. However, it does not make sense in a standard environment, since cars usually do not have a belly that might hurt them. 
(In a non-standard environment, like a fictional writing or TV show, a sentence like the second might be valid as well. For example, in a story where toys are "alive", the doll might tell the teddy bear *Dem Auto tut der Bauch weh.*, referring to the toy car.)

Answer (score 1):

In German, it is a trait of a verb what case (nominative, accusative, genitive, dative, all are possible) it rules. This does **not** change depending on the object's gender:

> Ich folge dem Mann
>
> Ich folge der Frau
>
> Ich folge dem Kind

(all dative).

Comment: Gender war aber nicht gefragt, sondern jmd. oder etwas.

Comment: @userunknown und was ist das anderes als Gender?

Comment: Das hatten wir aber schon 100 Mal: Der Löffel, die Gabel und das Messer sind 3 unterschiedliche, grammatische Geschlechter aber alles Sachen, nicht Personen. Während der Mensch, die Person und das Mitglied alles jemanden bezeichnen, nicht etwas.